# php dynamically fill variable or <select> tag from URL with spaces

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On a page, I have an HTML form with a `<select>` tag. This is dynamically filled with php... using content with spaces.

`<select text="52 state street" value="53 state street">`

On another page, I create the links to it.

```
<a href="example.com/page/?var=53%20state%20street">
```

Is there something I can replace the %20's with that will fix this issue?

Note Using WordPress and a plugin called "gravity forms". `?var` dynamically selects an option through the plugin I am using in WordPress. I don't think my issue is with WordPress or the plugin, but rather a lack of php knowledge. I don't have access to the html form code aside from filling it with variables (it is called in via shortcode).

Comment: What about `str_replace(' ', '-', $link);` ?

Comment: Other option: Is there a way to add a variable that still exists on both pages?

If so.. I could do something like the following:
on page1 (with link):
`<a href="example.com/page/?otherVar=53#state#street">`

on page2 (with form):
_replace **#** with spaces and assign to $var_

Comment: You really need the spaces to remain in the url?

Comment: @SinanSamet Thanks for the response. My problem with this is that it doesn't look quite as pretty for the end user. Unless perhaps there is a way to A: change the way the select's "text" is displayed to the user, or B: select the option by the value instead of the text.

I don't need the URL to have the spaces. but I would like the select options to have the spaces.

Comment: Lets say $var is the variable that holds your link that you send to page 2. Then do this `$var = str_replace(' ', '-', $var);` This will replace the spaces with `-` so `53 state street` would be `53-state-street` which won't be changed on the next page into ugly entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the urldecode function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `trim` function like this

`<?php
$str = "Hello World!";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo trim($str," ");
?>`

Output like this `HelloWorld`